# Odds of 2 people having same last 2 “numbers”

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Went inside a restaurant to pick up food and the attendant asked “order ending in 5a” both me and another person came up to pick it up.

Order number is a 8 digit string and it appears each digit can be a number (0-9), lower case letter (a-z), or upper case (A-Z)

What are the odds that two people would have the same last 2 digits of a 8 digit string?

I calculated the probability using Bayesian logic (1/65)*(1/65) but it seems quite low. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Welcome! You approach is correct, we are only interested in the last two characters matching. Your calculations are off though as Ross Millikan pointed out.

Comment: There is another consideration.  Suppose that you have $(50)$ people waiting.  $~\displaystyle (62)^2 = 3844.~$ Then, the probability that **not all** of the $(50)$ people have order #'s with distinct last two characters is $$1 - \left[\frac{3844 \times 3843 \times \cdots \times 3795}{(3844)^{50}}\right]$$ $$\approx 1 - \left[\frac{3820}{3844}\right]^{50} \approx 1 - (0.731) \approx 0.269.$$  So,  when $(50)$ consecutive people are called, there is approxmately a $(1)$ in $(4)$ chance that the sequence of $(50)$ order #'s will not all be distinct, with respect to the last two characters.

Comment: @user2661923 what formula did you use to calculate that? Want to think more about this problem! Thank you

Comment: Take a much simpler example.  Suppose that $(10)$ people are each going to be assigned a random positive integer, between $1$ and $100$ inclusive.  Further suppose that each assignment is done *with replacement*, so that the probability of any two people having the same number is $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{100}.~$.  Then, what is the probability that all $10$ numbers will be distinct?  ...see next comment

Comment: If there were only two people, this probability would be $$\frac{100}{100} \times \frac{99}{100}.$$  If instead, there were three people, this probability would be $$\frac{100}{100} \times \frac{99}{100} \times \frac{98}{100} = \frac{100 \times 99 \times 98}{(100)^3}.$$  The idea is that once the first person is assigned a number, there are only $(99)$ numbers that the 2nd person can be assigned, that do not match the 1st person.  Then, there are only $(98)$ numbers that the 3rd person can be assigned that do not match either of the other two people.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, with $10$ people, the computation is $$\frac{100}{100} \times \frac{99}{100} \times \cdots \times \frac{91}{100}$$ $$= \frac{100 \times 99 \times \cdots \times 91}{(100)^{10}}.$$  This pattern is consistent with my original computation, where there were $(62)^2$ possible two-character possibilities, instead of only $100$.

Comment: How were you able to get the (3820/3844)^50? I’ve tried proving it but failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I count $62$, not $65$, characters in the set.  Your idea would be correct if the characters are selected completely randomly, you selected two patrons and asked if their numbers matched.  If there are $50$ patrons waiting and they call your number the chance that some other patron has the same number is $49$ times higher.  It is quite possible that the next to last character is always a number and the last is always a letter.  The chance of a match is much higher then.